# Can I play Fate/Stay Night in English?

Tags: fate-stay-night

I am currently getting into the Fate/Stay Night anime, and learned that it originated in a 2004 visual novel of the same title.

While the anime is good so far, I am interested in playing the original visual novel, but I don't speak Japanese, so the versions I found so far are worthless to me.

I saw that there was a fan made translation patch, but I would rather play an official translation if it's available.

And so, has an English version of Fate/Stay Night been officially released?

Comment: I'm kind of confused if you're talking about an actual game or visual novel.  If it's a visual novel the [anime stackexchange site](http://anime.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask your question.

Comment: @BlueBarren: It is a actual game, under the form of a visual novel. As you can see from the only other question on that tag, it is composed of three executable for each "route" the player can take. However, Fate/Stay Night is also the name of a anime adapting one of the routes of the game.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're asking isn't something we can help with. We don't allow questions asking us to find resources that meet specific criteria; those ate recommendation questions. As for the legality, we don't touch that at all. We're not lawyers in any sense.

Comment: @DrakaSAN that's good to know since I thought visual novels fell under the category of book.

Comment: @Frank: On insight, I do agree it is really close to a "find that ressource". The goal of the question was more a "Did that game released outside japan". The legality and specific criteria were intended to prevent a "That dubious guy sell it with a english patch" pointing to dubious sources, but I should have known better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official English translation patch.

If you want to play it in English using a legal copy, the only way is to buy the original Japanese version and apply the unofficial English patch to it.